# How to count collections in Firebase SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I would like to get a count of items within the collection e.g. total number of images saved by users, so that I can display them in the app's home page. I have found this documentation from Firebase's website https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries. However, when I try to implement the code, I been getting a couple of error.

```
let query = db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
let countQuery = query.count
do {
    let snapshot = try await countQuery.getAggregation(source: .server)
    print(snapshot.count)
} catch {
    print(error);
}
```

Here are the errors I get. I have imported Firebase, FirebaseFirestoreSwift in the file.

[image]

I have try googling and searching for how to get data, but I could not find anything close from the internet. More specifically for SwiftI. Hope you guys can help me. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Count functionality was introduced relatively recently in [Swift SDK version 10.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_1000_-_october_10_2022). Are you using that or a later version?

Comment: Thanks, I was using 9.0. I have now updated it to V10. The errors went away, but i have a new error from line 245 count.Query which says -- "async call in a function does not support concurrency". Do you know how to handle this error?

Comment: Completion handlers and async await are not compatible. I suggest getting rid of the completion handler. You can watch “Meet async/await” for more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to update your firebase sdk.

The aggregation queries where introduced in version 10.0.0. If you are on an earlier version update your SPM package to the latest and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I was using 9.0. I have now updated it to V10. The errors went away, but i have a new error from count.Query -- "async call in a function does not support concurrency". Do you know how to handle this error?

Comment: You need to make the `countPasswords` function which contains this code async. Like ```func loadQuery() async {  your code } ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an SDK version where the COUNT functionality isn't available yet. Count functionality was introduced relatively recently in [Swift SDK version 10.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_1000_-_october_10_2022), so be sure to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I was using 9.0. I have now updated it to V10. The errors went away, but i have a new error from line 245 count.Query which says -- "async call in a function does not support concurrency". Do you know how to handle this error?